# Pass props to a react-redux component wrapped in a variable

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the following `_render` method inside my modal component:

```
  _render() {
    const {content: Content, className: customClassName} = this.props;
    let className = `${customClassName} modal-container`;
    ReactDOM.render(
      <Provider store={store}>
        <div className={className}>
          {Content}
        </div>
      </Provider>,
      this.modalTarget
    );
  }
```

which is called by `componentDidMount`:

```
  componentDidMount() {
    this.modalTarget = document.createElement('div');
    this.modalTarget.className = "modalContainer";
    this.container.appendChild(this.modalTarget);
    this._render();
  }
```

I'd like to pass the props received by my modal component, to `Content` component.

I already tried `<Content {...props} />`, but it throws:

```
Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object.
```

The Content is a react-redux component:

```
class NewGroup extends Component {

  _onSubmit(values) {
    //.....
  }

  _onCancel() {
    //.....
  }

  render() {
    const { handleSubmit } = this.props;
    return (
      <div>
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(this._onSubmit.bind(this))}>
          {_.map(FIELDS, renderField.bind(this))}
          <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary">Create</button>
          <button className="btn btn-primary" onClick={this._onCancel.bind(this)}>Cancel</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default reduxForm({
  validate,
  form:'NewGroup',
  fields: _.keys(FIELDS),
  fields_def: FIELDS
})(
  connect(null, { createGroup })(NewGroup)
);
```

`Content` is:

```
Object
   $$typeof: Symbol(react.element)
   _owner:null
   _self:null
   _source:null
   _store:Object
   key:null
   props:Object
   ref:null
   type:ConnectedForm()
   __proto__:Object
```

**Update 1**

Content actually comes from the router. I have a route list object, that maps the pathname to the components,

```
  'group/new': {
    'path': '/group/new',
    'component': GroupList,
    'props': {
      'modal': {
        'content': <NewGroup />,
        'className': 'new-group-modal'
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: `<Content {...props} />` should work, are you sure `Content` is your wrapped `NewGroup` component? You don't show the code where you populate the `content={}` prop

Comment: Yes, I found the issue, I have to actually change `<NewGroup />` to `NewGroup` just like `GroupList`.
(I updated the post)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue which was not visible in the original post was that you were passing a rendered `content: <Content />` component to your component containing `_render()`, when it should have been `content: Content` to pass the component class only.